# create ordering for php table without doing two queries to the database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$q4 = "SELECT order_id FROM menu WHERE category_id = $cat_id";
        $r4 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q4);

        $num_items = mysqli_num_rows($r4)+1;



        $q5 = "INSERT INTO menu (category_id, order_id, item, price, date_added, name) VALUES ('$cat_id', '$num_items', '$item', $price, NOW(), $name)";
        $r5 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q5);
```

As of right now im doing one initial query to get the total amount of rows in the table so I can add the right order_id to the newly inserted row.

Basically, I want to retain the 1,2,3,4 so I the user can edit the order themselves

Is there a way to do this in one query? Or perhaps you guys know a better method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A.** using composite primary key on `category_id, order_id`, and build an auto increment on that, like

```
create table menu
(
  category_id int(10) unsigned default 0,
  order_id int(10) unsigned auto_increment,
  item int(10) unsigned default 0,
  price double(10, 2) unsigned default 0,
  date_added datetime,
  name varchar(255),
  primary key(category_id, order_id)
);
```

**B:** use a sub-query during insert, like

```
insert into menu
(category_id, item, price, date_added, name, order_id)
select 
  $category_id as category_id, 
  $item as item, 
  $price as price, 
  now() as date_added, 
  $name as name,
  (select max(order_id) from menu where category_id=$category_id)+1 as order_id
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html) on your `order_id`. Then MySQL will automatically assign the next value to `order_id` as long as you don't explicitly specify one.

If you haven't, you should also set `order_id` to be unique.

Comment: i guess. but auto increment doesnt do it in consecutive order like 1,2,3,4... so if the user deletes 1,2,3,4 it'll start counting from 5... but i guess it really doesnt matter as long as it is retaining the order

Comment: There's a good reason why it doesn't reuse. Say you had data in other tables linked to `order_id=1`, if you deleted the order and then another one with the same ID was created, that other data would be incorrectly linked to the new order. IDs should be unique and never reused, there's no disadvantage to not reusing deleted IDs.